# Set a Render Target View to part of a texture direct X 11

Tags: directx-11, render-to-texture, rendertarget

I want to render to part of a texture in direct x 11.

Is there a simple way to just set the render target view to part of the texture?

If not, is there a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried binding your texture as render target and setting viewport accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `OMSetRenderTargets` to the render target you want to use
2. `RSSetViewports` to the viewport on the RT you want to render to.
3. `RSSetScissorRects` to ensure things are properly clipped to your viewport.